# Spring Security ldap Authentication through anotation

Tags: java, active-directory

We are trying to create a login page which will be authenticated via an ldap server.
For that we have created this below module which is not working. culd any one suggest the best way for authentication of ldap in spring security.

```
@autowired
Public void configAuthentication(AthenticationBuilder auth) throws exception{
   auth.ldapAuthentication()
   .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=")
  .groupSearchBase("ou=")
   .ContextSource()
.url("ldap://localhost:Port/dc=,dc=com")
}
```

error

```
Connection refused
```

Comment: The authentication credentials are correct?

Comment: yes the credentials are correct, I have checked it many time personally.